# Почему не работает миграция?

Tags: yii2

```
php migrate/create create_reviews_table
Could not open input file: migrate/create
```

Comment: в корне проекта надо написать "php **yii** migrate/create create_reviews_table"

Answer (score 0):

Перейдите через cd в корень проекта. Файл yii там, а не в модуле.

Если файл yii нет, то выполните команду php init

Comment: Так же не забудьте обратить внимание, что в *nix используется yii в корне, а в Windows yii.bat.